# std::forward description, which one is correct?

Tags: c++, std, forward

I was looking for `std::forward` and found two links whose description could be interpreted differently.

[cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/utility/forward/): Returns an rvalue ***reference*** to arg if arg is not an lvalue ***reference***.

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward): Forwards lvalues as either lvalues or as rvalues, depending on T

The difference is the ***reference*** I think.

Can you tell me which is the correct explanation? Thanks.

found descriptions and compare

Comment: `std::forward` is needed only in case of "perfect forwarding". Please search this keyword in your student book. Anyway this is useful only when writing own custom templates, which should not be done by beginner. So if you are beginner it would be better if you drop this topic for now.

Comment: the two sentences you quote are not in conflict. Did you read all the descpription?

Comment: cplusplus next sentence says "If arg is an lvalue reference, the function returns arg without modifying its type."

Comment: Both definitions are correct.  Depending on whether type T is an l-value reference, then the value is forwarded (read:  cast) as a, l-value reference (the same as type T), else as an r-value reference.

Comment: When in doubt, use the one in cppreference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cppreference is correct, and cplusplus is wrong

---

from the standard [§forward](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/forward)

> ```cpp
> template<class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept;
> template<class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept;
> ```
>
> - Mandates: For the second overload, `is_­lvalue_­reference_­v<T>` is `false`.
> - Returns: `static_­cast<T&&>(t)`.

---

notes

- the function always accept reference and returns reference.
- the template parameter `T` is always specify explicitly, it's never deduced from the function parameter `t` (or `arg`)

---

from cplusplus

> Returns an rvalue reference to arg if arg is not an lvalue reference.
>
> If arg is an lvalue reference, the function returns arg without modifying its type.

this is incorrect

- the rvalue (first) overload should result in error if `T` is lvalue reference type
- the lvalue (second) overload should return rvalue if `T` is rvalue (reference type)

---

from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)

> ```
> template< class T >
> constexpr T&& forward( std::remove_reference_t<T>& t ) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Forwards lvalues as either lvalues or as rvalues, depending on T
>
> ---
>
> ```
> template< class T >
> constexpr T&& forward( std::remove_reference_t<T>& t ) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Forwards rvalues as rvalues and prohibits forwarding of rvalues as  lvalues

this is correct.